# Pauses between jobs

Tags: concourse

We run a Bosh deployment on GCE and it is generally very stable. We scale workers from 2 at off-peak to 6 during the day. 4 core / 3.6 GB RAM / 100GB SSD machines.

Performance is generally good, but on occasion there are long pauses in between jobs (2-3 minutes), particularly if a lot of jobs are in progress. The spinner in the UI stops moving for the previous completed job, but the next does not start.

I presume this is related to provisioning containers for the next job, but is there some way we can speed up that operation. Is there some resource we can increase or tune that would improve that lag.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried upgraded to version 3.5.0 which has some performance tweaks? http://concourse.ci/downloads.html

Comment: We're on 3.9.0 and seems to see this. Interested to hear if you found a resolution.

Comment: Seems very similar to the problem described toward the end of this issue, where the bottleneck is in the DB: https://github.com/concourse/concourse/issues/1298